# align two div in css

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have 2 div : avatar and secondClass. I want these 2 div to be aligned, so I'm giving to both of them the css attribut "display: inline-block;"

Inside of "secondClass" I have the div "message", I'm it the css attribut "word-wrap: break-word;".

"avatar" and "secondClass" are only aligned when "message" is not too long, and I want them to be aligned no matter what.

my css are :

```
.firstClass{
    width: 80%;
}

.avatar{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.secondClass{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.message{
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;   
}
```

and my html code is

```
<div class="firstClass">
    <div class="avatar">
        <a href="aaaa"><img src="avatar.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="secondClass">
        <div class="message">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="firstClass">
    <div class="avatar">
        <a href="aaaa"><img src="avatar.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="secondClass">
        <div class="message">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example in this fiddle it's working on the first try but not on the second one:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ8Dr/

Comment: So you want `message` to have half of the width of `firstClass`?

Comment: yes but 50% is really random I'm really interested by the alignement of "avatar" and "secondClass"

Comment: So you want the `avatar` (say 50x50 px) on the left followed by a block for `message`.  The text of `message` will fill a certain width, preferably flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to give them a `max-width` so the `avatar` and the `secondClass` both do not go over 100% of `firstClass`. Have a look at that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ8Dr/2/).

For example:

```
.secondClass{
    max-width: 80%;
}

.avatar{
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include margin and padding in the percentage calculation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd let `.avatar` float left. Then the width of `.secondClass` is not important for the alignment.

```
.avatar {
    float: left;
}
```

and eventually (if you prefer):

```
.secondClass {
    margin-left: <width of .avatar>;
}
```